# Chrome, position fixed, and javascript problems

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, position, fixed

Like the title tells you, I have some problems with Chrome.

I got a backgroundimage that covers 100% width and height auto of the browsersize. The position is set to fixed. This works great in all browsers. 
But then I want to make my footermenu position fixed, and it just don't want to stay at the bottom of the page in Chrome!

It is at the bottom, as long as I don't scroll. When I scroll, the footermenu goes up. It only acts that way in Chrome. Anyone that have any idea of how I can fix it?

Another thing is that I have some javascript that looks like this:

```
function showContent() {
    document.getElementById('showbox').style.marginTop = '20px';
    document.getElementById('showcontent_btn').onclick = function() {hideContent();} 
    document.getElementById('showcontent_btn').id = 'hidecontent_btn';
}

function hideContent() {
    document.getElementById('showbox').style.marginTop = '30%';
    document.getElementById('hidecontent_btn').onclick = function() {showContent();} 
    document.getElementById('hidecontent_btn').id = 'showcontent_btn';
}
```

This is 2 functions, showContent makes my contentbox go up, 20px below the main menu, and hideContent makes the contentbox go down, 30% of the entire browser, so you can see the background image. It works great in all browsers, except for chrome...

In chrome, everytime I click the button, it looks like nothing happens, but if I start moving the mouse around, the part of the content I hover starts popping up and there is just parts of the content that is shown and it looks really messed up. To get rid of this, I have to refresh the page.

Please, help me with my problems. I've tried everything I know of and it doesn't work.

**EDIT: Here you have a working jsfiddle of the javascript functions: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8XPA/4/**

****EDIT2: Here is the HTML and CSS of the footermenu I want to be position fixed:
HTML:**

```
<div id="footer_menu"><?php print render($page['footer_menu']); ?></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#footer_menu { 
    position:fixed; 
    z-index:2; 
    bottom:0px; 
    width:100%;
    height:45px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

Best regards,
Daniel Lundahl

Comment: can you post a working jsfiddle example?

Comment: Here you have a working jsfiddle of the javascript functions: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8XPA/4/

Comment: Thanks for the example, however I'm not sure what's the problem with it.. Seems to do the same in chrome and ff here.

Comment: Yes, it works in jsfiddle, but not on my site. Don't know if there is something strange included. It's a drupal site.

No idea about the position:fixed; either?

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS

body,html{height:100%,width:100%}

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might be caused by the same thing that causes fixed elements to disappear sometimes when using jumplinks ([Fixed element disappears in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258877/fixed-element-disappears-in-chrome)). There is a bug in chrome that causes this to happen.

The solution that worked for me was adding this to the fixed element:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

By simply adding position: sticky (vendor prefixed), we can tell an element to be position: relative until the user scrolls the item (or its parent) to be 15px from the top:

```
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  top: 15px;
}
```

At top: 15px, the element becomes fixed.

[source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)