# 'transform3d' not working with position: fixed children

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-transforms

I have a situation where, in normal CSS circumstances, a fixed div would be positioned exactly where it is specified (`top:0px`, `left:0px`).

This does not seem to be respected if I have a parent that has a translate3d transform. Am I not seeing something? I have tried other webkit-transform like style and transform origin options but had no luck.

I have attached a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMX5H/1/) with an example where I would have expected the yellow box be at the top corner of the page rather than inside of the container element.

You can find below a simplified version of the fiddle:

```css
#outer {
    position:relative; 
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 20px , 0px); 
    height: 300px; 
    border: 1px solid #5511FF; 
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(100,180,250, .8); 
    width: 80%;
}
#middle{
    position:relative; 
    border: 1px dotted #445511; 
    height: 300px; 
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgba(250,10,255, .6);
}
#inner {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333; 
    height: 20px; 
    left: 0px;
    background: rgba(200,180,80, .8); 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    Blue: Outer, <br>
    Purple: Middle<br>
    Yellow: Inner<br>
    <div id="outer"> 
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="inner">
                Inner block
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make translate3d work with fixed-positioned children?

Comment: Same issue happens with filter too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937708/8620333

Answer (score 230, accepted):

This is because the `transform` creates a new  local coordinate system, as per [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-rendering):

> In the HTML namespace, any value other than `none` for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

This means that fixed positioning becomes fixed to the transformed element, rather than the viewport.

There's not currently a work-around that I'm aware of.

It is also documented on Eric Meyer's article: [Un-fixing Fixed Elements with CSS Transforms](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed that the actual specification had that info..... 

I guess I got the equivalent to the mathematical answer: "by definition" :)

Comment: @INT, I don't think there's going to be a workaround for this.  There's a major use-case for not allowing workarounds: user provided input could potentially cover controls outside of their designated area (think a malicious email adding options to the gmail toolbar).  The best workaround would be to avoid transforms for the time being if you're going to use fixed from inside of it.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the CSS top attribute to whatever window.scrollHeight is work? You might have to absolutely position it as well, but something like this should be doable, no? (too lazy to actually test right now)

Comment: @bradorego you were right, I just added the code I used.

Comment: This is still in flux in the spec as far as I can tell. See [Bug 16328 - Use of "containing block" does not match CSS2.1 definition](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=16328).

Comment: Easiest thing to do is have a wrapper div that has the fixed positioning with the transformed div within.

Comment: There is a workaround now, please mention it on your post. It's by rob.m 2 posts down.

Comment: The workaround mentioned in previous comment does not seem to work anymore. Note that in IE11 the element stays fixed as expected.

Comment: @BradleyOrego I also believe that works, but with the limitation that if the fixed content overflows you still cannot scroll...

Answer (score 14):

As Bradoergo suggested, just get the window `scrollTop` and add it to the absolute position top like:

```
function fix_scroll() {
  var s = $(window).scrollTop();
  var fixedTitle = $('#fixedContainer');
  fixedTitle.css('position','absolute');
  fixedTitle.css('top',s + 'px');
}fix_scroll();

$(window).on('scroll',fix_scroll);
```

This worked for me anyway.

Comment: It works! but instead of binding to "window", I had to bind to the div that was scrolling. Also, the fixed element flickers.

Comment: This could have done it, but like @train mentionned, it flickers.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't update near fast enough to be clean enough for my usage :-/ good idea tho

Comment: This is very bad practice, don't do style changes with js

Answer (score 12):

I had a flickering on my fixed top nav when items in the page were using transform, the following applied to my top nav resolved the jumping/flickering issue:

```
#fixedTopNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

[Thanks to this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258877/fixed-element-disappears-in-chrome)

Answer (score 6):

In Firefox and Safari you can use `position: sticky;` instead of `position: fixed;` but it will not work in other browsers. For that you need javascript.

Comment: Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning, and it's really **experimental**, I'd highly recommend to avoid this, as it's not standard yet.

Comment: AFAIK on Firefox and Safari you can simply use `position:fixed` and it would work as expected anyway.

Comment: @oriadam no, I have the issue when the parent uses translate3d and children's fixed position is flying around in some cases. Will try to use `sticky` while it' already supported by major browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: `sticky` may be a solution,it works at modern browser.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best method to deal with this is to apply the same translate, but break children that need to be fixed out of their parent (translated) element; and then apply the translate to a div inside the `position: fixed` wrapper.

The results look something like this (in your case):

```
<div style='position:relative; border: 1px solid #5511FF; 
            -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 20px , 0px); 
            height: 100px; width: 200px;'> 

</div>
<div style='position: fixed; top: 0px; 
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333; 
            height: 20px; left: 0px;'>
    <div style='-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 20px, 0px);'>
        Inner block
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hju4nws1/

While this may not be ideal for some use cases, typically if you're fixing a div you probably could care less about what element is its parent/where it falls in the inheritance tree in your DOM, and seems to solve most of the headache - while still allowing both `translate` and `position: fixed` to live in (relative) harmony.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same problem. The only difference is that my element with 'position: fixed' had its 'top' and 'left' style properties set from JS. So I was able to apply a fix:

```
var oRect = oElement.getBoundingClientRect();
```

oRect object will contain *real* (relative to view port) top and left coordinates. So you can adjust your actual oElement.style.top and oElement.style.left properties.

Comment: This works on IE and Chrome, but not on Android standard browser. The left is a number but it is always drawn on the position 0

Answer (score 0):

I have an off canvas sidebar that uses -webkit-transform: translate3d.  This was preventing me from placing a fixed footer on the page.  I resolved the issue by targeting a class on the html page that is added to the  tag on initialization of the sidebar and then writing a css :not qualifier to state "-webkit-transform: none;" to the html tag when that class is not present on the html tag.  Hope this helps someone out there with this same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply opposite transform to the child element:

```
<div style='position:relative; border: 1px solid #5511FF; 
            -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 20px , 0px); 
            height: 100px; width: 200px;'> 
    <div style='position: fixed; top: 0px; 
                -webkit-transform:translate3d(-100%, 0px , 0px); 
                box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333; 
                height: 20px; left: 0px;'>
        Inner block
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a dynamic class while the element transforms.`$('#elementId').addClass('transformed')`.
Then go on to declare in css,

```
.translat3d(@x, @y, @z) { 
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(@X, @y, @z); 
             transform: translate3d(@x, @y, @z);
      //All other subsidaries as -moz-transform, -o-transform and -ms-transform 
}
```

then

```
#elementId { 
      -webkit-transform: none; 
              transform: none;
}
```

then

```
.transformed {
    #elementId { 
        .translate3d(0px, 20px, 0px);
    }
}
```

Now `position: fixed` when provided with a `top` and `z-index` property values on a child element just work fine and stay fixed until the parent element transforms. When the transformation is reverted the child element pops as fixed again. This should easen the situation if you are actually using a navigation sidebar that toggles open and closes upon a click, and you have a tab-set which should stay sticky as you scroll down the page.

Answer (score -1):

One way to deal with this is to apply the same transform to the fixed element:

```
<br>
<div style='position:relative; border: 1px solid #5511FF; 
            -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 20px , 0px); 
            height: 100px; width: 200px;'> 
    <div style='position: fixed; top: 0px; 
                -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 20px , 0px); 
                box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333; 
                height: 20px; left: 0px;'>
        Inner block
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On IE bug does not exist in first place