# Using CSS transform scale breaks position:fixed

Tags: html, css, css-position, transform

I am experiencing an odd issue and am wondering if it's a bug in the rendering engines - it occurs in WebKit and also Firefox that I've tested.

If you have a `div` that's fixed on the page and you add another `div` inside it and also set it to be fixed (to obtain a fixed header within a fixed popup), you can ensure that the header will remain visible even when the user scrolls the popup. Unless you set `transform` `scale` on the popup - doing that will break `position:fixed` and cause it to no longer fix to the top of the parent `div` and instead it will scroll along with the content. Is that expected behavior - how can I work around that?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caw0veqo/3/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [webkit css 'transform3d' + 'position: fixed' issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/webkit-css-transform3d-position-fixed-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `transform: scale(x)` will break the element out of the coordinate flow and thereby can not have a fixed position.

I'd recommend instead wrapping the text below `#header` in a constrained `div` with `overflow: auto`. A `fixed` child of a `fixed` ancestor just doesn't make that much sense, but I can see what you were going for.