# position:fixed not playing nice with off canvas menu in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

***What's intended***

I'm using a [off canvas menu](http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/) using CSS and JavaScript. The off canvas menu is working as intended. I want a sidebar menu that is left of the screen and moves along when the menu is triggered. The idea is to have a menu trigger that is 100px across and has a height of 100% and always left of the screen. Using position absolute I had problems with the height on all browsers, using fixed position Firefox works fine but encounters problems mentioned below.

***Errors***

*Firefox Issues:* None, as far as I can tell.

*Chrome Issues:* After scrolling a few pixels down the sidebar menu trigger does not stretch the entire page.

*Internet Explorer:* The sidebar seems to vanish completely when the sidebar menu is triggered.

***jsFiddle***

Because my code is heavy on both HTML, CSS and JavaScript I have included a [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/sLf79m5d/14/). Please note that the problem only occurs on Chrome and Internet Explorer as far as I know. You can replicate the problem by scrolling down the page a little and then clicking the left hand side menu button.

***Screenshots***

[image: Off Canvas Menu Issues]

***NOTE WORTHY HTML CODE (Full Code in Fiddle)***

```html
<div id="sbContainer" class="sbContainer">
    <div class="sbPush">
        <header class="contain-to-grid sbMenu sbFX">
            <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
                <ul class="title-area show-for-small-only"><!--SITENAME--></ul>
                <section class="top-bar-section"><!--LINKS--></section>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="sbContent-one">
            <div class="sbContent-two">
                <div class="sbMenuTrigger" data-effect="sbFX"><!--SIDEBAR TRIGGER--></div>
                <div class="sbMainContent" role="document"><!--PAGE CONTENT--></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***NOTE WORTHY CSS CODE (Full Code in Fiddle)***

```css
html, body, .sbContainer, .sbPush, .sbContent-one {
    height:100%
}
.sbContent-one {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative
}
.sbContainer {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden
}
.sbPush {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    z-index:99;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .5s;
    transition:transform .5s
}
.sbPush::after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    content:'';
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s,width .1s 0.5s,height .1s .5s;
    transition:opacity 0.5s,width .1s 0.5s,height .1s .5s
}
.sbMenu-open .sbPush::after {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .5s;
    transition:opacity .5s
}
.sbMenu {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:244px;
    height:100%;
    background:#872734;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s
}
.sbMenu::after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    content:'';
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .5s;
    transition:opacity .5s
}
.sbMenu-open .sbMenu::after {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s,width .1s 0.5s,height .1s .5s;
    transition:opacity 0.5s,width .1s 0.5s,height .1s .5s
}
.sbFX.sbMenu-open .sbPush {
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(300px,0,0);
    transform:translate3d(244px,0,0)
}
.sbFX.sbMenu {
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);
    transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)
}
.sbFX.sbMenu-open .sbFX.sbMenu {
    visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .5s;
    transition:transform .5s
}
.sbFX.sbMenu::after {
    display:none
}
.no-csstransforms3d .sbPush,.no-js .sbPush {
    padding-left:244px
}
.sbMenuTrigger {
    background-color:#b23445;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0
}
.sbMainContent {
    margin-left:100px;
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    top:0;
    padding-top:50px;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: screenshots and fiddle do not match... not sure what the fiddle is demonstrating

Comment: Screenshots are taken from a development site. If you load fiddle in either chrome or internet explorer you can replicate the same issues displayed in screenshots..

Comment: chrome was fine for me, but I'm on Linux so it may give different results

Comment: Did you scroll down and then expand the menu?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a work-around that requires very little changes.

It works consistently in the latest versions of FF, Chrome, and IE11/10.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bch5kqha/)

```
.sbContent-one {
  overflow: visible;       /* Or remove overflow-x: hidden */
}
.sbMainContent {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.sbMenuTrigger {
  position: static;        /* Or remove position: fixed */
}
```

The easiest way to resolve the issue in Chrome is to simply move the `overflow` from `.sbContent-one` to `.sbMainContent`. In doing so, you can't actually scroll past the `.sbMenuTrigger` element (which resolves the issue) since `.sbMainContent` is a sibling element.

There are currently [many inconsistencies](http://codepen.io/markdebeer/pen/qrBDm) across browser around how `fixed` elements are [positioned relative to elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/webkit-css-transform3d-position-fixed-issue) that are [transformed using `translate3d`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-rendering). The issue in IE was due to the fact that `fixed` elements are positioned relative to the window without taking the elements that are transformed using `translate3d` into account. To solve this avoid fixed positioning completely, and add the element `.sbMenuTrigger` back into the normal flow by removing `position: fixed` (or overriding that with `position: static`, the default). In doing so, the sidebar expands as expected.

In other words:

- Remove `overflow-x: hidden` from `.sbContent-one` (or override it with `overflow: visible`).
- Add `overflow-x: hidden` to `.sbMainContent`.
- Remove `position: fixed` from `.sbMenuTrigger` (or override it with `position: static`).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for working solutions. I've granted Josh the reward as believe the solution fits my requirements while explaining the reason why it doesn't work. Plus 1 for everyone else! thanks!

Comment: @bybe Thanks. I just started another bounty which will be awarded to Joe since his solution worked as well.

Comment: Hey again, I just tested it on Safari 6 and 7, seems the menu is getting margin:56px from somewhere... using .sbContainer margin-left 56px resolves the problem when the menu is open but breaks it when its closed. Eeek! why can't browsers be the same :P

Answer (score 10):

Here is my solution to your problem. Tested on 3 mayor browsers and it works fine!

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3f0yLq8/3/)

Take a look at my changes on the following classes:

- remove position relative from `.sbContent-one`
- add height: 100% to `.sbContent-two` (new rule)
- major changes on `.sbMainContent`
- position absolute for `.sbMenuTrigger`

the main problems were:

1. unnecessary position relative and absolute position from `.sbContent-one` and `.sbMainContent`.
2. position fixed is relative to the window, so its behavior varies across browsers when you translate the element.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this.. have an upvote 1+.. It mostly works, although there is a slight caveat now that you have removed `position: relative`.. if you compare [your fullscreen example](http://jsfiddle.net/e3f0yLq8/3/show/) VS the [OP's fullscreen example](http://jsfiddle.net/sLf79m5d/14/show/), you will see that the positioning of the text *"Scroll Down and expand menu to see problem"* is now off.. I'm pretty sure the OP wants to maintain that relative positioning.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thats because of the JS fiddle header and iframe.if you manage to open a clean version you would see it works perfect. Also I suggested cleaning some styles that I think are unnecessary thats why I included more changes.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it working on last chrome/IE11.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLf79m5d/18/)

I moved the

```
        <div class="sbMenuTrigger" data-effect="sbFX">
            <div class="sbMenuIcon">
                <div class="sbMenuIconBackground"></div>
                <div class="sbMenuIconOverlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sbMenuLogo">
                <div class="sbMenuLogoBackground"></div>
                <div class="sbMenuLogoOverlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

At the end of the `<header>` tag, so the CSS became:

```
.sbMenuTrigger {
    background-color:#b23445;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-100px;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The position fixed + transform are not always welcome by all browsers.

Comment: Solves the issue but dislike the idea of using negative margins or positions. Additionally not sure what you did but the menu fails to close on your Fiddle.

Comment: Negative margin is not a problem when everything is fixed in width, for the fail to close, it's maybe a problem by the fact of moving HTML?