# Fixed position with ons-pull-hook component

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a button with position:fixed to stay at the same place when i scroll.

When i use the ons-pull-hook element in the same page, the button is moving with the scroller. It is no more fixed. how can I fix that ?

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with that arises when `translate3d` is used on a parent element of an element with fixed position.

Please see this question:
['transform3d' not working with position: fixed children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/webkit-css-transform3d-position-fixed-issue)

There is not good workaround. You could remove the transform from the `<div class="scroll">` element after the callback has been executed but it would still not look very nice:

```
$scope.load = function(done) {
  $timeout(function() {
    done();
    document.querySelector('.scroll').style.transform = '';
  }, 500);
};
```

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/WvNVwE

You shouldn't put code like this in the controller in a real app. This is just an example.

Does the button need to move when the page is pulled down? Otherwise you can just put it outside the `<ons-page>` element and wrap the whole thing in another `<ons-page>` element:

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-button style="position: fixed; top: 80px; left: 50%; transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0); z-index: 2000">Button</ons-button>

  <ons-page>
    <ons-pull-hook>
      Pull down
    </ons-pull-hook>

    ...
  </ons-page>
</ons-page>
```

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/NqWQbv

Comment: Thanks, i'll try the incredible double page solution ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I confirm ! The page wrapped in a page works perfectly !

thanks !!

```
  <ons-button style="position: fixed; top: 80px; left: 50%; transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0); z-index: 2000">Button</ons-button>

  <ons-page>
    <ons-pull-hook>
      Pull down
    </ons-pull-hook>
    ...
  </ons-page>
</ons-page>
```