# onClick toggle only selected element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been working on some toggle based buttons. I have two buttons one is buy and other is the demo. I have managed to write a bit of jQuery code for the toggle. everything is working fine except when I click on single button both of them are being toggled. But I want only one of it to be toggled. One other minor thing is when I click on the button some weird animation is being played I guess that is because I have used the toggle. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamm_98666/4ke04toL/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.theme-options').find('#buy').click(function() {
    $('.buy span').toggle(200);
  });

  $('.theme-options').find('#demo').click(function() {
    $('.demo span').toggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
body { position: relative; }
.theme-options {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.theme-options span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.buy,
.demo {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.buy span,
.demo span {
  display: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme-options">
  <span id="buy">User
<a href="#" class="buy theme">
  <span>Want to buy this theme</span>
  </a>
  </span>
  <span id="demo">User
<a href="#" class="demo theme">
  <span>Want to request a demo</span>
  </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont see what you mean. When I click the first button, the first button toggles. When I click the second button, the second button toggles. No idea what you mean with "both of them are being toggeled"

Comment: When you click on the first button the second button is also being toggled but not showing content. I want the send button to stay in the default place.

Comment: No it is not. The thing is, your "animation" that shows the content pushes the buttons away from the right side. The problem lies on your animation. not the toggling itsself

Comment: @TimGerhard Can you help me on that? I have only bit of knowledge regarding JQuery

Comment: It's a CSS issue Mohammed. Not a jQuery one. I may help you let me check...

Comment: Well of course I could help but I dont know how your animation is supposed to look

Comment: @TimGerhard It is just like two icons on the top right in fixed position. When you click on the icon the text rolls out from right to left.one can buy the theme or request demo. but I want this thing in mobile so I am not applying any hover effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to theme-options class taking width which is applying to both element so both will move on on toggle you can seperate them in different div and apply this

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.theme-options').find('#buy').click(function(){

      $('.buy span').toggle(500);

    });
    
      $('.theme-options2').find('#demo').click(function(){

      $('.demo span').toggle(500);

    });
  });
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.theme-options {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.theme-options span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.theme-options2 {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.theme-options2 span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.buy, .demo {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.buy span {
 display: none;
}
.demo span {
 display: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theme-options">
<span id="buy">User
<a href="#" class="buy theme">
  <span>Want to buy this theme</span>
  </a>  
</span>
</div>
<div class="theme-options2">
<span id="demo">User
<a href="#" class="demo theme">
  <span>Want to request a demo</span>
  </a>  
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: yes in toggle function you can apply value for animation check updated fiddle

Comment: One last thing as the toggle is making the animation weird can we use some other animation?

Comment: For that you need to give specific width to element but i think this is  good way then it

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

.theme-options {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .theme-options span {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

.theme-options1 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    right: 0;
    top: 80px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .theme-options1 span {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

.buy, .demo {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: block;
}

    .buy span, .demo span {
        display: none;
    }

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.theme-options').find('#buy').click(function () {
        $('.buy span').toggle(200);
    });

    $('.theme-options1').find('#demo').click(function () {
        $('.demo span').toggle(200);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="theme-options">
    <span id="buy">User
        <a href="#" class="buy theme">
            <span>Want to buy this theme</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="theme-options1">
    <span id="demo">User
        <a href="#" class="demo theme">
            <span>Want to request a demo</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ke04toL/51/)

Comment: I cant see any link.

Comment: Click on this link it usefull for you

Comment: One last thing as the toggle is making the animation weird can we use some other animation?

Comment: Use whatever animation you want, I get the impression you're wanting us to do the leg work here.  Do it yourself, or at least have a go.

Comment: which type of animation do you want

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this way

```js
$('#buy,#demo').click(function(){
        $(this).find('span').fadeToggle(300);
    });
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.theme-options {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.theme-options:nth-of-type(2) {
 top: 90px;
}
.theme-options span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.buy, .demo {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.buy span, .demo span {
 display: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theme-options">
<span id="buy">User
<a href="#" class="buy theme">
  <span>Want to buy this theme</span>
  </a>  
</span>

</div>
<div class="theme-options">
<span id="demo">User
<a href="#" class="demo theme">
  <span>Want to request a demo</span>
  </a>  
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working with animation but as I mentioned in the question it is going out with some weird movement. can we fix it.

Comment: You can try with `fadeToggle(100)` @Mohammedwahedkhan See updated snippet

Comment: One last thing as the toggle is making the animation weird can we use some other animation?

Comment: @Mohammedwahedkhan You can use `    transform: translateX();`

Comment: I tried it  Please read the first answer of this question : )   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071046/fixed-element-in-transform-translate-container-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.theme-options').find('#buy').click(function(){

        $('.buy span').toggle(200);
        if($('.demo span').css('display') == 'inline'){
          $('.demo span').toggle(200);
        }

      });

        $('.theme-options').find('#demo').click(function(){

        $('.demo span').toggle(200);
        if($('.buy span').css('display') == 'inline'){
          $('.buy span').toggle(200);
        }
      });
    });
```

is it what you want?
you need to judge whether another item is expand