# position: fixed not working after button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I got this header that is fixed and always going to stay on top during scrolling. and it works fine. but when i switch to responsive view and click my menu button and switch back to desktop view again, none of the position: fixed work...
here's my website: [Website](http://demo.codmod.ir)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include the relevant code to show your problem. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on getting the best help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the menu in responsive view it adds the inline `style="transform: translate3d(300px,0px,0px)"` to the `<div id=mp-pusher`> and when you close it it leaves the transform style there.

Transform styles break fixed positioning [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15256339/3585500).

When I changed the inline style to `transform: none;` in Chrome Dev Tools the `fix-menu` class worked again.

You need to remove the `transform` or set it to `none` when the mp-pusher closes.

Comment: you're right! just one more question... Why does this one works just fine? [link](http://www.ayandehcenter.com)

Comment: It works in IE11 but not Chrome 45. I did some digging and it looks like transform gives Chrome all sorts of issues with fixed position. A couple ideas. 1. Change line 205 in [mlpushmenu.js](https://github.com/codrops/MultiLevelPushMenu/blob/master/js/mlpushmenu.js#L188) from `this._setTransform('translate3d(0,0,0)');` to `this._setTransform('none');` or 2. [Use jquery to detect media query change from a class change](https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries) and remove it with `$('#mp-pusher').removeAttr('style');`. Not tested, but they might break the menu close.