# ng-gallery not overlaying the whole page

Tags: angularjs, gallery, accordion

In an Angular project, I'm using a [v-Accordion](https://github.com/LukaszWatroba/v-accordion) and inside one of its panes, there's a [ng-gallery](https://github.com/jkuri/ngGallery) component. 
Everytime a thumbnail is clicked, the ng-gallery overlay is opened inside the v-Accordion pane. How can I make it fullscreen (covering the body)?

Here is a Plunker demonstrating this issue:

```
  <h2>Outside Accordion</h2>
  <ng-gallery images="images"></ng-gallery>
  <br />
  <h2>Inside Accordion</h2>
  <v-accordion class="vAccordion--default" multiple>
    <v-pane expanded>
      <v-pane-header>
        Accordion
      </v-pane-header>

      <v-pane-content style="background-color:#dedede;">
        <pre>
          Content bla bla bla
          More Content
        </pre>
        <ng-gallery images="images"></ng-gallery>
      </v-pane-content>
    </v-pane>

  </v-accordion>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/V7BfPcRvpkwssOajC34X?p=preview

Comment: The reason it's not covering the body is v-Accordions CSS (translate3d) and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/webkit-css-transform3d-position-fixed-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got [fixed](https://github.com/LukaszWatroba/v-accordion/issues/37#issuecomment-187279960) with vAccordion v1.5.1 :)