# Child with position:fixed scrolls with position:fixed, overflow:auto parent

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a parent with `position:fixed; width/height:100%; overflow:auto` and a child that also has `position:fixed`. When the parent's content overflows and the parent starts scrolling I would expect the child to stay fixed in relation to the viewport. It does not.

the scenario is a slide down panel on top of the content using css transforms. The slide-down panel has a *close* button that should stay in view while the panel's content scrolls. Change the `.overlay-slidedown` class on the `.overlay` element to `.overlay-fade` and, in that case, the close button will stay in it's place.

https://jsfiddle.net/xajk7uez/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an extra layer within`.overlay` as a sibling to `.overlay-close` to only address the `overflow-y: scroll;` the `position: fixed;` on `.overlay-close` will work. This `.overlay-content` layer should also be 100% width/height

```
.overlay > .overlay-content {
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

See updated Fidle for the demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/n0wxfc60/2/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't do it but this is what I did. I moved the `overflow:auto` from the `.overlay` class to the  `.overlay-content` class which will have to also be 100% width/height

Comment: @lavirius My JSFiddle got broken somehow, I saved it with the last state... Glad it is resolved.

Comment: @lavirius Thanks for updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The Solution for your issue will be

placed the `.overlay-close` outside the `.overlay`

see my edits here https://jsfiddle.net/xajk7uez/5/

I believe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/webkit-css-transform3d-position-fixed-issue) addresses your issue.

Comment: Already did that. In this case the close button just shows ans hides while the panel slides down and up, instead of being part of the panel but staying fixed while the panel content moves.

Comment: then you should achieve that without using the transform.

Comment: If I not use the transform I am "achieving" something else... No, the solution, this far, is to have the scrolling content inside a childen container within the main container that slides down.