# Cross-browser fix - position: fixed as descendants of transformed elements

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-position, fixed, css-transforms

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/webkit-css-transform3d-position-fixed-issue) and discussed in [this chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574) according to [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering)

> In the HTML namespace, any value other than `none` for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

`position: fixed` that are descendant of any element with `transform` other than `none` are relative to that element.

---

However IE <= 11 and Firefox at least up to FF36 do not conform to the spec but position the element relative to the viewport (as originally intended).

**Is there any fix ("polyfill") to get the same behaviour across all browsers?**

Otherwise is there a way to "feature detect" instead of browser detect this behaviour to alternatively style affected elements?

Comment: it's broken the same way in chrome so maybe it's a webkit thing

Comment: Do you want all browsers to behave as per the spec or in the same way as the "broken" browsers?

Comment: @Shaggy Rather per spec but I wouldn't mind any solution as long as it's uniform across all browsers.

Comment: @CarolMcKay read through the linked sources for a detailed description of why/how/where it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any "polyfills" to force cross browser consistency in this situation so, as it is presented as an acceptable alternative in the question, I'll provide an answer to the part about "feature detection".

You could test whether or not the browser complies with the spec by creating a couple of temporary elements, one nested inside the other. Use `translatey()` to move the parent element down from its "natural" position and fix the `position` of the child element, with a `top` value of `0`. Then, by using [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), we can check whether or not the `top` of the child element is equal to that of the parent - if it is, the browser complies with the spec.

```js
var body=document.body,
    div=document.createElement("div"),
    span=document.createElement("span"),
    compliant;
div.style.transform="translatey(100px)";
span.style.position="fixed";
span.style.top=0;
div.appendChild(span);
body.appendChild(div);
compliant=span.getBoundingClientRect().top===div.getBoundingClientRect().top;
body.removeChild(div);
console.log(compliant);
```