# FullPage JS Fixed Background Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, jsfiddle, fullpage.js

I'm trying to get a fixed background to work with Fullpage JS. No matter what I do the backgrounds stay there or they don't show up at all.  I tried a JS Fiddle but I can't get that to work at all either. https://jsfiddle.net/jpking72/jqa7wapt/9/

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.4/jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.4/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

#fullsite {
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

#section1 {
  background:url(/images/pwHoustonDowntown.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 fixed / cover;
}

#section2 {
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

#section3 {
  background:url(/images/pwHoustonWindow2.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 fixed / cover ;
}

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#fullsite").fullpage({

})

})

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullsite">
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <h1>
    Section 1
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">
  <h1>
Section 2
  </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section3">
  <h1>
  Section 3
  </h1>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Answer (score 3):

[That's a bug in some browsers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/webkit-css-transform3d-position-fixed-issue) Nothing to do with fullpage.js. Fullpage.js uses the `translate3d` property of css3 which is the one causing the bug in some browsers.

To solve it you have two options:

- Use `css3:false` in fullpage.js options. It won't go as fluid, but you'll have your fixed background working.
- Use `scrollBar:true`. You'll get a scrollbar and it might not go as fluid as well.

As you can see in the [fixedBackgrounds.html provided in in fullpgae.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/backgroundsFixed.html), it uses css3:false.

```
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: false,
            //to avoid problems with css3 transforms and fixed elements in Chrome, as detailed here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/208
            css3:false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jquery into your project. Jquery should be included first

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#fullsite").fullpage({

     });
});
```

Comment: @TheHawk Your jquery should be first. Working link: https://jsfiddle.net/9nj3w684/2/