# Floating Action Button not scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material2, angular-template

I have a FAB contained in two `div` tags from parent (`app.component.html`) where one of them uses transform: translate3d.
When scrolling down the page, the FAB is 'stuck' and doesn't scroll.

I want this FAB to overlay this entire HTML page (specifically: `<div class="page-content">`)
HTML:

```
  <div cdk-scrollable="" class="mat-sidenav-content" ng-reflect-ng-style="    " style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; transform:     translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="page-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-carbuilder _nghost-wxw-148="">
            <button style="position: absolute;bottom: 16px;right: 16px;z-index: 5" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"  aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="demo" md-fab>
            <md-icon>
              directions_car
            </md-icon>
          </button>
        <div class="page-content">
            <p>content</p>
    </div>
```

(Native image upload didn't work)
Here's how it looks before & after scroll:

[Before](http://i63.tinypic.com/2ytz4i1.jpg)
[After](http://i66.tinypic.com/mkx89i.png)

Note:
[Similar but not duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children)
[Related](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/998) 
[Also Related](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2205)

Comment: have you tried setting the yellow car's position to fixed so it follows the flow of the page when you scroll? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp, cannot really guide you more since you are posting like 2% of your code:)

Comment: @UnknownPotato, Yes I have. This didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is caught up with this problem, there is no solution. Google's Material theme has addressed the issue [here](https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav):

> FABs inside sidenav
>
> For a sidenav with a FAB (or other floating element), the recommended
>   approach is to place the FAB outside of the scrollable region and
>   absolutely position it.

In other words:
1. Place the Fab in your "app.component.html" (or parent component's HTML)
2. use *ngIF to determine if the current route (or component) is active, if true -> display the FAB.

Answer (score 1):

They use CSS transform on .mat-sidenav-content.
CSS transform creates a new local coordinate system.

Fix to remove transform:

```
.mat-sidenav-content {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Though it resets their intention to force hardware acceleration.

Comment: since they're using CSS transform to create a new local coordinate system, wouldn't it be counter-intuitive to go against the wave? Instead, is there a way to work with the transform correctly?