# Why sticky Bootstrap top navigation menu bar does not stick to the top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I'm trying to make a site with *Fullpage.js* & *Twitter-Bootstrap* and you can see the entire website here at this [url](http://gooyanet.com).

As you can see when u scroll down ,the navigation menu hides however I have correctly used the `navbar-fixed-top` class.

Here's the full code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- This following line is optional. Only necessary if you use the option css3:false and you want to use other easing effects rather than "linear", "swing" or "easeInOutCubic". -->
        <script src="vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>
        <!-- This following line is only necessary in the case of using the plugin option `scrollOverflow:true` -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
        <title>Gooyanet</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                    sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2','#4BBFC3','#7BAABE','whitesmoke'],
                    css3: true
                 });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fullpage">
            <div id="header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="topMenu">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gooyanet</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#">دنیای ای تی</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">طراحی بازی</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">طراحی اپلیکیشن</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">سرویس پیام کوتاه</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">برنامه نویسی ویندوز</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">وب هاستینگ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">طراحی سایت</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu1">
                                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Forgot Something?</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="slide"><img src="images/image-slide-one.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" style=""/></div>
                <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                asdsad 
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="section">Sction 2</div>
            <div class="section">Sction 3</div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that it works fine without the *fullpage.js* plugin but I need to use both of them together. So do u have any solution to this ?

Comment: I disabled all css from fullpage.js, and it still removes the navbar after it's below the header. Open your dev tools, select the 'header' div and fiddle with the css to find out what works! Once you find everything that is disabling the 'static', edit your css files to mirror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed element has to be placed outside the fullPage.js wrapper. In this case, outside the element with `id='fullpage'`

This is due to [a bug in certain browsers dealing with fixed positioned elements and translate3d transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children).

fullPage.js uses 3d transformations on the `id='fullpage'` element unless you use the option `css3:false`, which will result in a worse performance.