# css3 transform not rendering properly on chrome (works on firefox)

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have a div, on which I am applying css3 transform to make it look 3d & these transforms change as per the `mousewheel` events.

First look at the div (the brown board with dots) in normal state:

[image]

Now I apply this small css code to transform it!

```
.board-class{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: center top;
    transform: translateY(0) rotateX(30deg);
}
```

you can guess what this code will do, right? But it does not work in expected way, this is how it renders on chrome:

[image]

But on Firefox this work well without issue:

[image]

Here is link to hosted site : http://www.buildactivityboard.com/how-it-works

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong, this seems like a silly issue but I can't find out what I am doing wrong.

**Note:**

Believe me, this used to work without issue on Chrome too! I don't know what happened now to cause this problem. I've checked this on Mac & Windows, behaviour remains same!

Comment: Looks good to me in chrome.

Comment: CSS3 isnt a standard yet, browsers implement the features as they think it should, which may result in unexpected results.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me on Chrome. (version 52)

Comment: For older versions maybe use `-webkit-transform-style`, `-webkit-transform-origin` and `-webkit-transform`.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: chrome 57 does it perfect and 58 has the described bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the position from static to absolute fixes the issue:

```
.master-board .widget-board {
  width: 750px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  margin: -96px 0 0 -375px;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574

Comment: Thanks, it did worked, I knew that fixed divs behave weird when ancestor in transformed, but I was unable to relate it here!

Answer (score 0):

Either adding `perspective: 1000px` to `body` or `.master-board` works.

EDIT: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children/15256339#15256339), seems like it's caused by a conflict between 3d transforms and position:fixed. The chromium bug tracker marked this issue as "wont fix".

I've created a fiddle to reproduce this issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/uuhqsw57/

Adding perspective to its nearest parent helped solve the issue.

Comment: Yes it worked, but I've added `perspective:1000px` to `.hw-master` div, parent div of the board!

Comment: Checking your css, wait a min

Comment: Adding the perspective to `.master-board` also works. Seems like the inheritance failed to work, probably some sort of chromium bug here. According to @Gerard, maybe the position is the cause of the bug.

Comment: Yes, thanks, It surely a bug, thats why it was working previously, then my chrome updated itself :)

Comment: Most of the time, this problem (pespective is lost when set in the grand-parent) arises from a missing transform-style: preserve-3D in the middle element (the parent of the transformed element, the son of the pespective element)

Comment: @vals IMHO, I don't quite agree with your idea. Missing preserve-3D only treats the 3D object as a 2D representation of the object - like a cube on a paper, instead of an actual cube. Perspective on the other hand has do deal with resizing of some the surfaces and the actual rendering.