# Position fixed elements jump around when loading or redirecting iframe (iPad only)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, iframe

To see the problem clearly. Please take a look on the following YouTube video.
[Position fixed elements jump around when redirecting iframe](https://youtu.be/71TvKDInmSY)

or try the widget on this site (iPad)
[Naiise](https://naiise.com)

> Note: The site in video is different from the site above since the
>   owner doesn't wanna use the widget anymore before the problem is
>   fixed. But they are having the same problem.
>   One more thing: All fixed elements on the parent site jump around not only the iFrame. It likes, on iPad, the fixed elements need to be recalculated position when redirecting pages inside an iFrame.

Here is a simple code that I created to simulate the issue. Please create a html file from it and run it on iPad simulator or real device to see the problem.

```
<html>
    <body style="height: 10000px">
        <div style="color: #ffffff; width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red; position: fixed; left: 20px; bottom:300px;">
            Other fixed element
        </div>

        <iframe style="height: 500px; width: 420px; position: fixed; bottom: 95px; right: 20px;" src="https://printskitchen.eber.co" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both the sites are different. Could you share the link in the video ?

Comment: They are using same widget and had the same problem. Because the site is reporting the issue don't wanna use the widget anymore before the problem is fixed, I can't give you the link.

Comment: @HoangTrung are you using any custom style to the plugin to change its position.?

Comment: @JithinRajPR No, I don't. I only use css for the position. It just likes when redirecting inside the iFrame, it affects to fixed position elements. If you notice, in the above site, the chat plugin  which is fixed position also jump around.

Comment: @HoangTrung Did you tried using `!important` after your style - `position:fixed !important`

Comment: Are there any transforms going on anywhere in the CSS?

Comment: @AmitJS94 The link in the video is [ionmagazine.co.uk](http://ionmagazine.co.uk), you can see it pretty easily.

Comment: @stybl no this is only transform css that i used for iframe holder -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

Comment: @JithinRajPR I just tried, doesn't work.

Comment: @HoangTrung, In your console can you check if the style is overwritten by plugins style.? and which is the style which is overwriting your style.?

Comment: @HoangTrung Your websites URL is invalid. Could you provide some fiddle or fix it?

Comment: @maszynka sorry, updated the website url

Answer (score 5):

The problem is caused by the `translate3d` transformation that you apply on the `iframe`;

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

There is a well known problem in which `translate3d` causes `position:fixed` elements to behave like `position:absolute` in certain webkit browsers, such as those on iOS, as well as certain desktop versions of chrome.

Here is a demo which demonstrates the bug in action:

```css
html,
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#nav{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:red;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    height:500%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <nav id="nav">
  </nav>
  <main id="content">
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

In the demo, the red nav should be visible even after scrolling down. Depending on your browser, this may or may not work properly as is. Removing the problematic `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` style makes it work properly across all browsers.

This bug occurs due to the transform creating a new coordinate system, causing the `position:fixed` element to become affixed to the transformed element instead of the viewport.

I myself came across this bug while trying to smooth out transitions on iOS, and created a post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360874/smooth-out-css-transitions-in-ios-without-causing-positionfixed-elements-to-mal). **More information can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children) thread** which I have also linked to in my own post.

The only surefire fix I know of is to remove the problematic `translate3d` style. If it is necessary, for example in order to coax iOS into enabling hardware acceleration (which is what I needed it for), then try applying it to different elements, either **parents** (body, html), or **children** of the iframe holder.  I found that applying it to a completely unrelated element gave me the desired result.

There are also several case-specific workarounds and fixes in the thread I have linked to. One of those might do the trick.

It is a pretty nasty bug to track down. Took me a while to find it on my own page.

Best of luck.

Comment: Actually I got the problem before adding transform3d style. I just added it to see if it can fix the problem.
As you suggest, I also removed it to check but it doesn't work. Still jumping around when redirect the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if you change the position from fixed to absolute it'll work perfectly. 
You can follow the following tutorial to emulate the fixed position by abosolute position
https://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-emulate-css-fixed-positioning-on-mobile-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid changing `height` and `display` property (you should remove `opacity` as well). Instead, give #iframe-holder `will-change: transform;` and try to:
`transform: translateX(150%);` when widget should be collapsed.

It should not cause widget to render again (the problem might be rendering issue), and you will benefit in performance.

Comment: Thanks. There is no problem with collapsing widget, it's about redirecting pages inside an iFrame affect to all fixed position elements in the parent site not only the iFrame, but I also updated my code follow your suggestion, unfortunately the problem is still there.

Comment: It looks for me as an issue with size change, position or display property (it shouldn't move if it's not the case).Please provide some fiddle with code that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added the demo code in question description. Please run it on iPad to see the problem.