# make the top div fixed

Tags: html, css

Im using native CSS and html (no jquery no js and no bootstrap).
I managed to make the left column to be fixed and i put the scrollbar on top.

Now I want the top row to be fixed when scrolling down (marked in red).

[image]

Google spread sheet made it good: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ai9kcTj5hLFKkBAx3TRFfhKMYR9MFgHAFJAC-BTgmqM/edit?usp=sharing

you can play with this:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPpNRL

```css
.wrap{
  width:100%;
}
.left-col .col,.right-col .col{
  border:solid 1px #ffd6d6;
}
.symbol{
  line-height:35px;
}
.row .col{
  line-height:35px;
  float:left;
  
}

.left-col{
  width:250px;
  float:left;
}
.right-col{
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
.head{
  line-height:35px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.right-col .row .col{
  width:250px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:none;
}

.right-col ,.right-col .row .col {
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left-col">
    <div class="symbol col" style="height:52px;font-weight:bold">Symbol fixed</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row head">
      <div class="col">A fixed</div>
      <div class="col">B fixed</div>
      <div class="col">C fixed</div>
      <div class="col">D fixed</div>
      <div class="col">E fixed</div>
      <div class="col">F fixed</div>
      <div class="col">G fixed</div>
      <div class="col">H fixed</div>
      <div class="col">I fixed</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, is there any specific reason that you are using `transform: rotate(180deg)`?

To "fixate" an element to the window you can use the css property `position:fixed`.

To do this I've added the following code:

```
.head{
  line-height:35px;  /* was already here from your own code */
  font-weight:bold;  /* was already here from your own code */ 
  position:fixed;
  background:#fff;
  top:0;
}
```

This will fixate the `.head` container to the top.

Please also note that I've move the order of your HTML, moving the `.head` row up underneath the `.symbol` container. Without `position:fixed` this will remove the need for using `transform:rotate(180deg)` which I can't really see the reason behind so far (?) - hence I've also deleted the `transform:rotate()` part.

I've also added `margin-top: 36px` to the `.right-col` to "push" this container down, to make sure that the `.head` element isn't placed above the first row and thereby hiding some of the content. I've also  added `margin-top: -36px` to the `.left-col` to align it with the `position:fixed` head element.

One last thing I've done is to remove the margin of the `body` (which you haven't done explicitly and hence is added automatically from the browser). Otherwise the `top:0` would leave a gap between the left-hand row and the top of the window.

The example can be seen here:

```css
.wrap{
  width:100%;
}
.left-col .col,.right-col .col{
  border:solid 1px #ffd6d6;
}
.symbol{
  line-height:35px;
}
.row .col{
  line-height:35px;
  float:left;
  
}

.left-col{
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  margin-top: -36px; /* This is added */
}
.right-col{
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  margin-top: 36px; /* This is added */
}
.head{
  line-height:35px;
  font-weight:bold;
  position:fixed;
  background:white;
  top:0;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.right-col .row .col{
  width:250px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left-col">
    <div class="symbol col" style="height:52px;font-weight:bold">Symbol fixed</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
    <div class="symbol col">EURUSD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
        <div class="row head">
      <div class="col">A fixed</div>
      <div class="col">B fixed</div>
      <div class="col">C fixed</div>
      <div class="col">D fixed</div>
      <div class="col">E fixed</div>
      <div class="col">F fixed</div>
      <div class="col">G fixed</div>
      <div class="col">H fixed</div>
      <div class="col">I fixed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">A</div>
      <div class="col">B</div>
      <div class="col">C</div>
      <div class="col">D</div>
      <div class="col">E</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">G</div>
      <div class="col">H</div>
      <div class="col">I</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. while im reading, 2 thinkgs. the reason i made the flip is because i want to scrol bars tp be on top of the page. Please also note that the top left col should be fixed as well. (Symbol fixed). thanks again.

Comment: Aha! Well that makes it a bit more tough since the `transform:rotateX()` creates a new stacking layer in which the `position:fixed`-elemnt now is fixed to instead. Furthermore, as far as I know, making the `.head` element fixed removes the possibility to scroll it by scrolling the `.right-col` element without the use of javascript. This is because, as the `fixed` attribute suggest, it's fixated to the window and hence follows the movement, maintaining it's initial position.

Comment: You can read more about the stacking order "issue" here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children]and view an example of the "scroll issue" here: https://jsfiddle.net/mj2gze9h/4/