# Scrolling the content behing fixed element is not happening

Tags: css, css-position

Please see the following page:
https://dogcollars-3.myshopify.com/products/short-sleeve-t-shirt

I am trying to fix the position of the "order details" box so it stay at prominent position and content behind it scroll. This is a Shopify prebuilt theme. I have applied the following additional CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

  .product-single {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }

  .order-details {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 70%;
    background: rgba(255,255,0,0.2);
    position: fixed;  
  } 
}
```

The 'order details' element is positioned correctly but not fixed. This element scrolls along with the content behind this layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with `transform: translate3d` styles on element `.page-container`.

Commenting these styles the problem goes away, 'Others detail' element would be fixed. You can try to comment/uncommend in the fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/nLbntzqk/

---

**EDIT:** 
Now I've found more info, see ['transform3d' not working with position: fixed children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children) for more detail explanation.

Comment: ah you beat me on time ! i just found it :) +1

Comment: Panther, you are great. Many many thanks! 

what if i remove the following code in my theme? 

.page-container {
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

Comment: what exactly translate3d(0, 0, 0);  do?

Comment: @SSaurabh... what if you remove this code? `Position: fixed` would work, for example. You don't need this `transform` there. Read attached link for more info, or try to google - now you know what you need to find.

Comment: Thank you sir. I become fan of your!