# Disable sidebar scroll, if gemini scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

### 1. Summary

If I use [**gemini-scrollbar**](https://github.com/noeldelgado/gemini-scrollbar) instead of native scrollbar, I can't make, that my sidebar don't scroll.

---

### 2. Data

- my sidebar in `aside` tag,
- content of my article in `main` tag.

[image: aside and main]

My minimal example code (see also [**in Codepen**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/JLXBzX)):

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sticky demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gemini-scrollbar/index.js" defer></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var scrollbar = new GeminiScrollbar({
                element: document.querySelector("body"),
                autoshow: true,
                forceGemini: true,
            }).create();
        };
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gemini-scrollbar/gemini-scrollbar.css">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            /*overflow: hidden;*/
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        aside {
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url("https://kristinita.ru/theme/images/aside/SashaGreenSweater.jpg");
            float: left;
        }

        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
            aside {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
            aside {
                width: 35%;
                position: fixed;
            }
            main {
                width: 65%;
                float: right;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente officia ipsum ut harum voluptates, esse unde nam nobis minus nemo cumque, rerum odit aliquam vitae dicta, aliquid eveniet veritatis totam.</div>
        <div>Magnam eos esse reprehenderit saepe, natus, placeat quas alias eum facilis, unde explicabo velit eaque dicta nostrum recusandae iste culpa. Quidem nisi architecto ratione atque recusandae ea sequi adipisci incidunt.</div>
        <div>Recusandae pariatur ex, a quisquam! Aperiam blanditiis quisquam, officia aut vel, minima laboriosam quam, cumque in maiores enim id unde, deserunt numquam! Vel eligendi qui sunt reprehenderit hic, numquam dolorum.</div>
        <div>Sunt quas iste autem accusantium, illo non praesentium quam accusamus impedit repudiandae voluptate harum maiores tenetur dolorem corrupti dolore magnam, a. Magni error eligendi reiciendis repudiandae quod autem nesciunt magnam.</div>
        <div>Ullam assumenda velit ad amet totam nemo molestiae expedita temporibus, aliquam. Unde maxime, totam laborum eligendi minima consequatur, sequi voluptate cumque eveniet, beatae libero eius quis omnis ut, repellendus porro.</div>
        <div>Cumque nostrum natus omnis temporibus minima unde, similique explicabo provident possimus assumenda molestiae aperiam accusantium odio, non, beatae saepe magnam fugit. Fuga incidunt quae id quisquam expedita sequi, nesciunt ullam.</div>
        <div>Temporibus commodi a numquam soluta tempore, facilis voluptate. Dolore ut, harum, aperiam maxime distinctio quisquam aliquid officiis, laudantium voluptates repudiandae eveniet voluptas laborum debitis autem rem earum soluta temporibus iste!</div>
        <div>Sed quia excepturi dolorem dolores. Quaerat nisi blanditiis sequi atque deleniti eligendi aliquam ad ipsam culpa natus, impedit numquam dolor maiores quisquam repellat officia voluptate omnis ex doloremque sed sint!</div>
        <div>Tenetur consequatur eligendi excepturi nihil, deleniti aliquam. Ut aliquam, laudantium, nostrum necessitatibus, maiores ad neque praesentium illo enim atque repellat amet totam vero cumque aut nemo pariatur perspiciatis iusto id.</div>
        <div>Fuga optio eligendi quaerat facere sint nesciunt corrupti necessitatibus! Ea impedit, quasi veniam hic recusandae ipsum incidunt vitae cum, voluptates modi repellat provident beatae quo doloremque rerum illo. Esse, consectetur.</div>
        <div>Sunt beatae ex ab, cum dignissimos, eligendi doloribus provident! Adipisci itaque voluptate numquam est quae nisi ut dolor repudiandae modi tempora doloribus reiciendis corporis, blanditiis sed dolore ratione! Voluptatum, placeat.</div>
        <div>Natus nobis nisi alias, facilis quae porro. Error doloremque quidem harum obcaecati quasi animi molestiae itaque accusamus, et eligendi. Sapiente quisquam mollitia fugiat quos voluptatibus assumenda. Consectetur ratione, officiis eos.</div>
        <div>Commodi obcaecati, nemo. Repellendus voluptatem, voluptatibus vero, assumenda molestias dolorem maiores dolore delectus odit magnam numquam corrupti possimus quibusdam error quae repudiandae in est quod tempora accusantium odio hic quaerat.</div>
        <div>Ea eligendi, dolor nostrum necessitatibus porro hic qui repellat soluta veniam similique, ab quae vero, ipsam obcaecati error accusamus. Fugiat temporibus sed magnam repudiandae totam nam minus obcaecati enim, voluptatibus!</div>
        <div>Autem dignissimos voluptatem velit molestias recusandae id minima, provident accusantium consequatur, aut temporibus corrupti quaerat quasi quis adipisci numquam minus in rerum dolorum, optio delectus atque ex aspernatur perspiciatis expedita.</div>
        <div>Repellat aspernatur sequi, ad veniam veritatis rerum necessitatibus hic voluptatibus delectus dolore eaque quasi in quaerat deserunt, sunt. Recusandae praesentium quibusdam nihil sapiente magni eum iusto iste esse ex a!</div>
        <div>Obcaecati omnis adipisci laboriosam temporibus, delectus enim debitis earum voluptatibus, culpa impedit quia et eaque nesciunt. Quos, incidunt debitis. Veniam quaerat nihil maxime numquam eaque beatae delectus, quo ex harum.</div>
        <div>Enim illum non, accusantium quas sed quisquam minus aut illo, expedita voluptatum? Odio iure sequi, maiores repellendus quasi ratione distinctio consequatur quaerat perferendis. Iusto eum tempora nostrum necessitatibus, reiciendis aperiam.</div>
        <div>Beatae doloribus, officia repellat illo provident temporibus numquam accusamus. Excepturi, tempora unde alias officiis architecto ex odio voluptatum autem adipisci, voluptas sed quos, praesentium pariatur quia tenetur sequi veniam fuga!</div>
        <div>Harum quibusdam sequi repudiandae culpa voluptas reprehenderit quod eaque earum odio. Earum vitae non reprehenderit incidunt, eveniet error eum nihil iure sapiente cum, nesciunt, fuga accusamus nulla natus. Obcaecati, quaerat.</div>
        <div>Autem dicta recusandae, esse saepe? Expedita consectetur ipsa vitae at esse provident, accusantium molestias, labore, neque totam ullam blanditiis autem perspiciatis minima deleniti iure veniam! Numquam veritatis saepe molestias tempora.</div>
        <div>Nesciunt esse similique unde laudantium deleniti. Debitis dignissimos magni exercitationem nulla eius pariatur ducimus minima reiciendis! Eligendi saepe aspernatur laudantium necessitatibus ipsam sed, maxime a. Inventore velit itaque, obcaecati magni.</div>
        <div>Repudiandae nam dolores perspiciatis totam minus incidunt, error nihil itaque facere alias, perferendis sit vel! Culpa delectus, maiores assumenda accusamus amet maxime dolores, rerum! Accusantium ipsum distinctio numquam aperiam dolore.</div>
        <div>Officiis tempore quae sint iste facere corporis eius ea quos sapiente, et, quo dolore repellat commodi magni quam reprehenderit quisquam perspiciatis nihil ducimus nisi maiores necessitatibus. Non minus, fugiat tempore.</div>
        <div>Aspernatur maxime veniam reiciendis quo animi perspiciatis magnam, quidem quos itaque consectetur ratione eius. A, repudiandae consequatur quam doloribus suscipit harum, commodi numquam, in fugit et nostrum quo sunt ex!</div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### 3. Expected behavior

If [**I use native browser scrollbar**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/jzqpRX), `position: fixed` help me:

[image: Native]

---

### 4. Actual behavior

If [**I use gemini-scrollbar**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/JLXBzX), `aside` scroll with `main`:

[image: Gemini]

---

### 5. Not helped

For example:

#### 5.1. [**Theia Sticky Sidebar**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/BrKPex)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/resize-sensor/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/theia-sticky-sidebar/dist/theia-sticky-sidebar.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('main, aside').theiaStickySidebar({
            additionalMarginTop: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**Result**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/VXaGwW).

#### 5.2. [**Sticky sidebar**](https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sticky-sidebar/dist/jquery.sticky-sidebar.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('aside').stickySidebar({
        topSpacing: 60,
        bottomSpacing: 60
    });
</script>
```

[**Result**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/gerdrz).

---

### 6. Do not offer

Please, do not offer:

#### 6.1. “Don't use gemini-scrollbar”

I don't know another custom scrollbar, that:

- replace native body scrollbar,
- works without critical bugs,
- open source,
- active maintained.

#### 6.2. “Use `document.querySelector("main")` instead of `document.querySelector("body")`”

I have some problems in my site, if `document.querySelector("main")` in landscape orientation.

For example, user open [**anchor of any page of my real site**](https://kristinita.ru/IT-articles/Fastest-way-to-add-new-version-of-Sublime-Text-3-package#release-itjson) → user resize screen from landscape to portrait or conversely → scrollbar move to begin of my page. I don't know, how I can fix this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Summary

As [**answered plugin owner**](https://github.com/noeldelgado/gemini-scrollbar/issues/46#issuecomment-374928170), I need to add:

```css
.gm-scrollbar-container .gm-scroll-view {
  transform: initial;
}
```

---

### 2. Demonstration

[image: Demo]

- Codepen:

  - [**Sources**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/yjYvNr)
  - [**Demo page**](https://s.codepen.io/Kristinita/debug/yjYvNr/yokZEQdyVERA)
- Stack Overflow:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sticky demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gemini-scrollbar/index.js" defer></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var scrollbar = new GeminiScrollbar({
                element: document.querySelector("body"),
                autoshow: true,
                forceGemini: true,
            }).create();
        };
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gemini-scrollbar/gemini-scrollbar.css">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            /*overflow: hidden;*/
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        aside {
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url("https://kristinita.ru/theme/images/aside/SashaGreenSweater.jpg");
            float: left;
        }

        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
            aside {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
            aside {
                width: 35%;
                position: fixed;
            }
            main {
                width: 65%;
                float: right;
            }
        }

        .gm-scrollbar-container .gm-scroll-view {
          transform: initial;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <!-- Content -->
    <main>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente officia ipsum ut harum voluptates, esse unde nam nobis minus nemo cumque, rerum odit aliquam vitae dicta, aliquid eveniet veritatis totam.</div>
        <div>Magnam eos esse reprehenderit saepe, natus, placeat quas alias eum facilis, unde explicabo velit eaque dicta nostrum recusandae iste culpa. Quidem nisi architecto ratione atque recusandae ea sequi adipisci incidunt.</div>
        <div>Recusandae pariatur ex, a quisquam! Aperiam blanditiis quisquam, officia aut vel, minima laboriosam quam, cumque in maiores enim id unde, deserunt numquam! Vel eligendi qui sunt reprehenderit hic, numquam dolorum.</div>
        <div>Sunt quas iste autem accusantium, illo non praesentium quam accusamus impedit repudiandae voluptate harum maiores tenetur dolorem corrupti dolore magnam, a. Magni error eligendi reiciendis repudiandae quod autem nesciunt magnam.</div>
        <div>Ullam assumenda velit ad amet totam nemo molestiae expedita temporibus, aliquam. Unde maxime, totam laborum eligendi minima consequatur, sequi voluptate cumque eveniet, beatae libero eius quis omnis ut, repellendus porro.</div>
        <div>Cumque nostrum natus omnis temporibus minima unde, similique explicabo provident possimus assumenda molestiae aperiam accusantium odio, non, beatae saepe magnam fugit. Fuga incidunt quae id quisquam expedita sequi, nesciunt ullam.</div>
        <div>Temporibus commodi a numquam soluta tempore, facilis voluptate. Dolore ut, harum, aperiam maxime distinctio quisquam aliquid officiis, laudantium voluptates repudiandae eveniet voluptas laborum debitis autem rem earum soluta temporibus iste!</div>
        <div>Sed quia excepturi dolorem dolores. Quaerat nisi blanditiis sequi atque deleniti eligendi aliquam ad ipsam culpa natus, impedit numquam dolor maiores quisquam repellat officia voluptate omnis ex doloremque sed sint!</div>
        <div>Tenetur consequatur eligendi excepturi nihil, deleniti aliquam. Ut aliquam, laudantium, nostrum necessitatibus, maiores ad neque praesentium illo enim atque repellat amet totam vero cumque aut nemo pariatur perspiciatis iusto id.</div>
        <div>Fuga optio eligendi quaerat facere sint nesciunt corrupti necessitatibus! Ea impedit, quasi veniam hic recusandae ipsum incidunt vitae cum, voluptates modi repellat provident beatae quo doloremque rerum illo. Esse, consectetur.</div>
        <div>Sunt beatae ex ab, cum dignissimos, eligendi doloribus provident! Adipisci itaque voluptate numquam est quae nisi ut dolor repudiandae modi tempora doloribus reiciendis corporis, blanditiis sed dolore ratione! Voluptatum, placeat.</div>
        <div>Natus nobis nisi alias, facilis quae porro. Error doloremque quidem harum obcaecati quasi animi molestiae itaque accusamus, et eligendi. Sapiente quisquam mollitia fugiat quos voluptatibus assumenda. Consectetur ratione, officiis eos.</div>
        <div>Commodi obcaecati, nemo. Repellendus voluptatem, voluptatibus vero, assumenda molestias dolorem maiores dolore delectus odit magnam numquam corrupti possimus quibusdam error quae repudiandae in est quod tempora accusantium odio hic quaerat.</div>
        <div>Ea eligendi, dolor nostrum necessitatibus porro hic qui repellat soluta veniam similique, ab quae vero, ipsam obcaecati error accusamus. Fugiat temporibus sed magnam repudiandae totam nam minus obcaecati enim, voluptatibus!</div>
        <div>Autem dignissimos voluptatem velit molestias recusandae id minima, provident accusantium consequatur, aut temporibus corrupti quaerat quasi quis adipisci numquam minus in rerum dolorum, optio delectus atque ex aspernatur perspiciatis expedita.</div>
        <div>Repellat aspernatur sequi, ad veniam veritatis rerum necessitatibus hic voluptatibus delectus dolore eaque quasi in quaerat deserunt, sunt. Recusandae praesentium quibusdam nihil sapiente magni eum iusto iste esse ex a!</div>
        <div>Obcaecati omnis adipisci laboriosam temporibus, delectus enim debitis earum voluptatibus, culpa impedit quia et eaque nesciunt. Quos, incidunt debitis. Veniam quaerat nihil maxime numquam eaque beatae delectus, quo ex harum.</div>
        <div>Enim illum non, accusantium quas sed quisquam minus aut illo, expedita voluptatum? Odio iure sequi, maiores repellendus quasi ratione distinctio consequatur quaerat perferendis. Iusto eum tempora nostrum necessitatibus, reiciendis aperiam.</div>
        <div>Beatae doloribus, officia repellat illo provident temporibus numquam accusamus. Excepturi, tempora unde alias officiis architecto ex odio voluptatum autem adipisci, voluptas sed quos, praesentium pariatur quia tenetur sequi veniam fuga!</div>
        <div>Harum quibusdam sequi repudiandae culpa voluptas reprehenderit quod eaque earum odio. Earum vitae non reprehenderit incidunt, eveniet error eum nihil iure sapiente cum, nesciunt, fuga accusamus nulla natus. Obcaecati, quaerat.</div>
        <div>Autem dicta recusandae, esse saepe? Expedita consectetur ipsa vitae at esse provident, accusantium molestias, labore, neque totam ullam blanditiis autem perspiciatis minima deleniti iure veniam! Numquam veritatis saepe molestias tempora.</div>
        <div>Nesciunt esse similique unde laudantium deleniti. Debitis dignissimos magni exercitationem nulla eius pariatur ducimus minima reiciendis! Eligendi saepe aspernatur laudantium necessitatibus ipsam sed, maxime a. Inventore velit itaque, obcaecati magni.</div>
        <div>Repudiandae nam dolores perspiciatis totam minus incidunt, error nihil itaque facere alias, perferendis sit vel! Culpa delectus, maiores assumenda accusamus amet maxime dolores, rerum! Accusantium ipsum distinctio numquam aperiam dolore.</div>
        <div>Officiis tempore quae sint iste facere corporis eius ea quos sapiente, et, quo dolore repellat commodi magni quam reprehenderit quisquam perspiciatis nihil ducimus nisi maiores necessitatibus. Non minus, fugiat tempore.</div>
        <div>Aspernatur maxime veniam reiciendis quo animi perspiciatis magnam, quidem quos itaque consectetur ratione eius. A, repudiandae consequatur quam doloribus suscipit harum, commodi numquam, in fugit et nostrum quo sunt ex!</div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### 3. Explanation

`transform` property in `gemini-scrollbar.css`: [**1**](https://github.com/noeldelgado/gemini-scrollbar/blob/59c862051e32f350b5ee31d812f012ef4cdd5e54/gemini-scrollbar.css#L60), [**2**](https://github.com/noeldelgado/gemini-scrollbar/blob/59c862051e32f350b5ee31d812f012ef4cdd5e54/gemini-scrollbar.css#L80).

[**`transform` create a new local coordinate system**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15256339/5951529).

The `initial` keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default value.

---

### 4. Additional links

- [**CSS `initial` Keyword**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp)
- [**CSS `transform` Property**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)