# Prevent CSS transform affects childs

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to apply CSS `transform` property to two elements(Parent and child) But the problem is when i adding `transform` to parent then it affects child positioning.

An Example:

```js
$('.dropdownToggler').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown').toggleClass('-isOpen')
});

$('.test').click(function() {
  $('.topbar').toggleClass('transform');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.topbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 45px;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  /* remove comment below */
  /*transform: translateY(0);*/
}

.topbar.transform {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.dropdown {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  /* main styles */
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
  will-change: transform;
}

.dropdown.-isOpen {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.test {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topbar">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <button class="dropdownToggler">Open Menu</button>
    <button class="test">toggle `transform` to parent</button>
    <div class="dropdown">Notifications</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When you add `transform: translateY(0);` to the topbar (Parent) then notifications panel(Child) positioning based on parent. I'm trying to prevent this behavior.

For smoother animations, I've used `transform`, of course, we can use CSS `top`. Any suggestion? Thank you for devoting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the height of `.dropdown` in viewport units (100vh - the height of the `topbar`)

Example:

```js
$('.dropdownToggler').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown').toggleClass('-isOpen')
});

$('.test').click(function() {
  $('.topbar').toggleClass('transform');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.topbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 45px;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  /* remove comment below */
  /*transform: translateY(0);*/
}

.topbar.transform {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.dropdown {
  background: #ddd;
  height: calc(100vh - 45px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 45px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  /* main styles */
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
  will-change: transform;
}

.dropdown.-isOpen {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.test {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topbar">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <button class="dropdownToggler">Open Menu</button>
    <button class="test">toggle `transform` to parent</button>
    <div class="dropdown">Notifications</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, Can you please describe why this happens to transform?

Comment: Seems to be a few similar questions. This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15256339/5561605