# Position fixed is not working in any browser

Tags: html, css

My Site link: https://staging.kelsan.biz:8144

I want the header div class `getHeaderTopFixed` to be static. For that I have applied the below styles

```
box-shadow: gray 0px 0px 5px !important; 
position: fixed; 
top: 0px; 
width: 100%; 
z-index: 9000;
```

But is not working. Need suggestions on fixing this issue.

Comment: refer this:-https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` on the parent  `<div class="off-canvas panelwrap" role="panel-wrap">`. Take a look here to fix problem : ['transform3d' not working with position: fixed children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children)

Comment: We made [role="panel-wrap"] {transform: unset !important;} and this work for us.

Answer (score 0):

please add this to your css you can use z-index according to you.

```
#header {position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index:999!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
```

Comment: please remove your `base.css`. put this css alone. will work fine. TESTED OK.

Comment: removing base.css entirely collapse design of our site..Is there any other solution to fix this issue without removing base.css?

Comment: okay i'll give you a short work. check line no:6311 of base.css and remove the following code `#header {
    /* position: relative; */
}


` this is enough. no need to put any code. this will solve the problem. don't forget to mark this as answer. cheers

Comment: we made  #header { /* position: relative; */ } in the base.css but still issue is not resolved.

Comment: then replace the header css with above css and try

Comment: it seems like the header is fixed