# Using a filter breaks any child elements using position: fixed

Tags: css, css-filters

I'm currently running into an issue using css filter. When used on a div that contains a div with `position: fixed`, the child element will suddenly get positioned relative to the parent with the filter.

With the following code I see the elements positioned the way I want them to be:

**HTML**

```
<div class="blurred">
  I'm blurred
  <div class="something-fixed">
    I'm fixed
  </div>
</div
```

**CSS**

```
.blurred {
  margin: 10% 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* filter: blur(2px); */
}

.something-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

However when applying a filter, for instance blur, the `position: fixed` seems to be ignored:

[image]

What exactly is causing this behaviour and how can I fix it?

I've created a codepen to demonstrate the behaviour [here](https://codepen.io/csteur/pen/jeabza)

Comment: same issue happen with transform : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's the same indeed thanks! Putting the filter on the html tag won't work for me though