# CSS scale jitter on one of 2 div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I put 2 `<div>` side by side and added both a scale animation and an overlay on hover. Yet the left side jitters when the mouse moves inside the area while the right side is quite stable on hover.

[image]

I thought both sides are using pretty much the same code and could not figure out the cause of this problem. What caused the jitter?

[code here](https://codepen.io/amarthgul/pen/jOOLxWZ)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #222, #222 10px, #333 10px, #333 20px);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.showcase {
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cameraShowcase {
  width: 47.5%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.cameraShowcase:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.cameraShowcase:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.wheelShowcase {
  width: 47.5%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.wheelShowcase:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.wheelShowcase:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.overlay {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}

#leftOverlay {
  left: 0;
}

#rightOverlay {
  left: 5%;
}

.textContainer {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 15%;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <div class="cameraShowcase">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="camera" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="leftOverlay">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <h3>Camera and Sensors</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wheelShowcase">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="wheel" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="rightOverlay">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <h3>Power System</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having a complex case of stacking elements. You set your overlay element `position:absolute` and the first positionned ancestor is `showcase` so initially both overlay are overlapping and filling the width of `showcase`

Remove the opacity to notice this:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #222, #222 10px, #333 10px, #333 20px);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.showcase {
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cameraShowcase {
  width: 47.5%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.cameraShowcase:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.cameraShowcase:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.wheelShowcase {
  width: 47.5%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.wheelShowcase:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.wheelShowcase:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.overlay {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}

#leftOverlay {
  left: 0;
}

#rightOverlay {
  left: 5%;
}

.textContainer {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 15%;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <div class="cameraShowcase">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="camera" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="leftOverlay">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <h3>Camera and Sensors</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wheelShowcase">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="wheel" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="rightOverlay">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <h3>Power System</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now on hover you add `scale()` to the parent element of your overlay which will make them positionned relatively to them since `transform` [change the containing block of absolute and fixed element.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15194313/8620333)

So you will have this:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #222, #222 10px, #333 10px, #333 20px);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.showcase {
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cameraShowcase {
  width: 47.5%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.cameraShowcase:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.cameraShowcase {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.wheelShowcase {
  width: 47.5%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.wheelShowcase:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.wheelShowcase:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.overlay {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}

#leftOverlay {
  left: 0;
}

#rightOverlay {
  left: 5%;
}

.textContainer {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 15%;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <div class="cameraShowcase">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="camera" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="leftOverlay">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <h3>Camera and Sensors</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wheelShowcase">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="wheel" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="rightOverlay">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <h3>Power System</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You are toggling between both states and since in the first one you have an overlap, you will get that bad effect where you are losing the hover effect. It doesn't happen with the second image because its overlay is on the top so you will never loss the hover.

To avoid this you can keep transform on your element initially or consider `position:relative` on them to make sure your overlay elements are positioned relatively to their parent and never overlap:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #222, #222 10px, #333 10px, #333 20px);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.showcase {
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cameraShowcase {
  width: 47.5%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.cameraShowcase:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.cameraShowcase:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.wheelShowcase {
  width: 47.5%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.wheelShowcase:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.wheelShowcase:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.overlay {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity:0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}

#leftOverlay {
  left: 0;
}

#rightOverlay {
  left: 5%;
}

.textContainer {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 15%;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <div class="cameraShowcase">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="camera" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="leftOverlay">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <h3>Camera and Sensors</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wheelShowcase">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="wheel" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="rightOverlay">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <h3>Power System</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a incredibly clear and concise explanation, thank you so much X3

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to your cameraShowcase and wheelShowcase:

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
```

Comment: I see, so the problem is about the `display` I assume?

Comment: As @temani has just pointed out you had your elements stacking on top of one another

Comment: note the display:inline-block is not needed when using float

Comment: @temani I did notice that i get a warning when i use display:inline-block with float:left however just out of habit i have left it in place. Is there any reason as to why it is a bad idea to have them used together other then it has no effect?

Comment: it's not a bad idea, it's simply useless as it has no effect ... if you are aware about this you can keep it or remove it but it may lead people to think that it's needed to have where it's not.