# Could not set position:fixed for body

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to fix `menu-card` as position : fixed for `screen`. But it sets at top of the `center-grid` not for `screen`.

This is the Link of my codes
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-tdbx6i?file=pages%2Findex.js

index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const contentMenuOpenHandler = () => {
    document
      .getElementById('contentMenu')
      .classList.add(styles.open_content_menu);
    console.log('hiiiiii');
  };

  const contentMenuCloseHandler = () => {
    document
      .getElementById('contentMenu')
      .classList.remove(styles.open_content_menu);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.left_grid}>hi1</div>
        <div className={styles.center_grid}>
          <div>
            <p>
              {' '}
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id quo
              iusto officia deserunt aliquam numquam optio at eum eos. Nemo
              beatae possimus ipsum quam distinctio odio minus maiores
              quibusdam. Quaerat sint dolorum impedit repellat corrupti libero
              aperiam natus assumenda, voluptatem sequi accusamus minima ut
              provident ipsam exercitationem dolorem id, officiis possimus
              repudiandae nam eius dicta recusandae. Facere consectetur labore
              suscipit, dolorum, sequi placeat impedit animi eum fugiat,
              assumenda voluptatum corrupti. A expedita earum nam voluptatem in
              dolor laborum ducimus, inventore temporibus obcaecati ipsum harum
              ex reiciendis! Hic, ex deserunt reiciendis fugit laborum nulla
              nobis consequuntur molestias. Autem quisquam a odio dolorum ab
              magnam unde, re
            </p>
            <div
              id="contentMenuBtn"
              className={styles.content_menu_btn_grid_wrapper}
              item
              xs={12}
            >
              <div className={styles.content_menu_btn}>
                <button className={styles.btn} onClick={contentMenuOpenHandler}>
                  <svg className={styles.svg} viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
                    <path d="M4 10.5c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5s.67 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm0-6c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5S3.17 7.5 4 7.5 5.5 6.83 5.5 6 4.83 4.5 4 4.5zm0 12c-.83 0-1.5.68-1.5 1.5s.68 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.68 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zM8 19h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1s-.45-1-1-1H8c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1s.45 1 1 1zm0-6h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1s-.45-1-1-1H8c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1s.45 1 1 1zM7 6c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1s-.45-1-1-1H8c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1z" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <p>
              pudiandae itaque delectus commodi. Molestias numquam sunt velit
              corrupti animi dignissimos, necessitatibus deserunt repellat
              veniam voluptates magnam eius veritatis ab quis inventore tempora.
              Rerum ullam velit, natus, praesentium beatae aliquam mollitia enim
              corrupti commodi accusamus deserunt soluta perferendis tempora
              iure laborum quaerat culpa voluptatem veritatis impedit tempore
              fugit atque iste? Quos neque possimus nihil illo recusandae?
              Laborum animi unde aspernatur, veritatis incidunt magni eos
              facilis non iste aut iure atque explicabo! Dolorem, maxime ea.
              Vel, magnam ad, similique tempore tempora aspernatur, alias culpa
              quas saepe excepturi deleniti reprehenderit in deserunt omnis nemo
              rem exercitationem eveniet possimus repellat minus expedita? Iure
              unde minus nostrum ducimus quidem? Reprehenderit, numquam aperiam!
              Voluptatum, ab pariatur? Maxime, dolores eveniet! Quam sapiente
              placeat labore ipsam, doloribus facilis eveniet obcaecati
              praesentium cumque consectetur, temporibus magnam! Molestias
              veritatis id magni, eius sint totam culpa non ex ad fugiat fugit
              nam ullam, neque ipsam maxime est unde voluptates repudiandae
              aperiam qui! Eum quasi nemo beatae saepe labore reiciendis, enim
              sit iusto ipsum. Enim atque laborum, quisquam quia odit mollitia?
              Dignissimos corporis tempora quasi numquam, cumque non vero odit
              consequatur nisi dicta inventore exercitationem quam rerum
              voluptas eius voluptatem quos. Sunt est rem provident
              reprehenderit nemo ullam illum, tenetur aspernatur rerum. Porro
              accusantium veritatis consequatur explicabo temporibus. Ullam,
              expedita! Ratione possimus recusandae consectetur porro libero
              quaerat. Doloribus suscipit itaque, obcaecati quibusdam omnis
              explicabo libero ab cupiditate voluptates tenetur quis blanditiis
              consequatur sit dicta placeat voluptas, veritatis error
              consectetur sed ratione quidem reiciendis? Recusandae perferendis,
              expedita hic quod placeat quo tempore aspernatur itaque, aperiam
              quis ad a natus vero libero, maiores possimus. Ullam libero
              similique asperiores dignissimos quaerat nobis temporibus quam
              distinctio sapiente perspiciatis, officiis, excepturi, pariatur
              illum cupiditate inventore necessitatibus voluptates deserunt
              magnam quas ipsa unde. Exercitationem, vitae suscipit itaque
              perferendis obcaecati nisi iusto incidunt eum fugiat odio dolore.
              Reiciendis consequatur in, praesentium vero beatae iure ratione
              assumenda distinctio reprehenderit voluptate. Rerum deserunt
              tempore facilis sapiente totam magni, quam tenetur, sed
              repudiandae atque labore. Tempore voluptas debitis quam quis
              pariatur nam, dolor libero voluptatum impedit doloribus,
              temporibus soluta eum, atque sunt fugit voluptatibus similique
              sint assumenda asperiores eos. Architecto ut provident ad! Non
              reprehenderit quo inventore vero, reiciendis deserunt
              necessitatibus voluptatibus id magnam, eum ratione eligendi illo
              natus eos voluptatem optio hic ex aut. Modi adipisci facilis,
              labore quasi minus recusandae nam dignissimos inventore maxime.
              Consequatur assumenda illum et temporibus accusantium sint impedit
              ullam deleniti praesentium hic sunt velit tempore asperiores, id
              corrupti vero ab veritatis eum aliquid inventore sequi
              necessitatibus dolor ad? Placeat quia natus architecto ut dolorum
              fugiat atque pariatur itaque, velit dolor recusandae sunt. A nulla
              tempore numquam deserunt libero dicta nisi deleniti quam? Esse
              repudiandae, quisquam soluta itaque quo molestias placeat? Porro
              ducimus, tenetur mollitia numquam consectetur impedit nulla
              incidunt nostrum fugit neque illo enim possimus culpa corporis
              iure accusantium dicta earum exercitationem obcaecati molestias
              cupiditate saepe. Quod enim atque iste facere repellendus
              quibusdam nihil ipsam ea modi. Error molestias corrupti quibusdam
              consequuntur sapiente enim consectetur deserunt quas reiciendis
              nisi pariatur, dolor assumenda nesciunt, dolores, excepturi
              obcaecati officiis. Quo provident, a delectus quia maxime
              accusantium amet minima, nobis quas necessitatibus voluptas magnam
              ipsum tenetur porro, est quod labore veniam! Voluptatum quo
              tenetur quisquam dolorem nemo possimus expedita quidem? Accusamus
              impedit eum facilis accusantium, molestiae assumenda explicabo
              corrupti nobis doloribus nisi sequi sint eaque aspernatur ab cum
              numquam saepe nam tempore illum dolores ea labore, fuga facere.
              Sed inventore error amet incidunt, quibusdam qui provident,
              nesciunt sint omnis ipsa porro ab temporibus impedit! Hic iste
              voluptatem quisquam? Deleniti magni quaerat, ipsam dolor deserunt
              modi dicta at repellat. Minima sed, rerum ipsa autem quo sit,
              placeat eaque amet, adipisci omnis quam ullam exercitationem
              asperiores! Eveniet vel beatae reprehenderit consequuntur
              accusamus officiis optio ut non facilis animi aliquam odio tempora
              minima, perferendis incidunt maiores magni quae quas laboriosam
              quo iste veritatis aperiam, vero in. Vitae error perspiciatis
              quidem accusamus enim reprehenderit quod voluptatem delectus! Qui
              amet quia perferendis sed dolore id exercitationem saepe veritatis
              sequi. Cum, iusto laudantium quod minima odio dolorum praesentium
              aliquid unde voluptatem expedita architecto impedit modi
              inventore. Voluptatem deleniti non ipsum. Corporis, totam eos
              doloribus nihil molestias libero, dicta sit debitis numquam atque
              ipsum placeat ullam labore incidunt assumenda iste aspernatur
              necessitatibus voluptatum iure qui hic, tempora officiis vitae!
              Quis hic itaque sit nihil consectetur facere, quo, cum blanditiis
              provident illo, totam sunt? Quidem itaque incidunt iure voluptate
              quia? Animi magnam architecto, consectetur
            </p>
            <p>
              laboriosam quas voluptatum accusamus placeat necessitatibus
              voluptatem ipsam tempore assumenda aliquid sequi quisquam
              voluptatibus, amet excepturi reprehenderit ea iusto provident! Ea
              beatae enim modi nobis quibusdam soluta culpa suscipit dolor
              perspiciatis exercitationem fugit necessitatibus consequatur
              repellendus quidem, perferendis ullam quasi, aut tempore! Natus
              accusantium atque ipsum reprehenderit? Et atque iste, cum esse
              quia assumenda, explicabo dolore asperiores enim possimus
              laudantium molestias eveniet a impedit facilis earum
              exercitationem blanditiis obcaecati consequuntur deleniti, laborum
              nesciunt inventore voluptates? Vel ullam vitae aliquid sapiente
              quas ea ipsam in eaque, aut culpa dolor autem ad architecto, harum
              eum ex accusantium earum officiis itaque? Ullam, provident porro
              maxime cum, quos consequuntur officiis architecto laborum ut vel,
              itaque impedit sit sunt atque natus reiciendis accusantium
              molestiae esse numquam. Voluptas, magni! Beatae commodi adipisci
              repudiandae eveniet illum saepe nobis aspernatur id accusamus,
              tenetur similique voluptatibus enim dolorum, iure nam ipsam
              officia sed. Dicta rerum nesciunt saepe illo consequatur. Eveniet
              voluptas necessitatibus hic deleniti reprehenderit quidem quod
              quisquam modi! Nihil ipsum fuga hic labore provident? Accusantium,
              rem.{' '}
            </p>

            <div id="contentMenu" className={styles.menu_card_warapper}>
              <div className={styles.close_btn_block}>
                <button
                  className={styles.close_btn}
                  onClick={contentMenuCloseHandler}
                >
                  Close
                </button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.right_grid}>hi3</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

home.module.scss

```
.main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: rgb(104, 104, 23);
}
.center_grid {
  max-width: 56%;
  flex-basis: 56%;
  width: 56%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
.left_grid {
  position: fixed;
  width: 22%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 22%;
  flex-basis: 22%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right_grid {
  position: fixed;
  width: 22%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 22%;
  flex-basis: 22%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content_menu_btn_grid_wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  top: 60vh;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.content_menu_btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: -3.5rem;
}

.btn {
  background-color: pink;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(#000, 0.3);
  margin-top: 4rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  fill: white;
}

.open_content_menu {
  display: block !important;
}

.menu_card_warapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px black solid;
}

.close_btn_block {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I need, when I click `Menu-button` the `menu-card` should open and it should fix center of the screen. **When I scroll it should not move**. and **When I close the curse should be in initial stage not on the top of the `center-grid`**

What is the issue in my codes? Anyone give me the solutions please.

Thanks

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question please.

Comment: @cloned I added the link of my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-tdbx6i?file=pages%2Findex.js

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-tdbx6i?file=pages%2Findex.js

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` won't work when you apply `transform: translate` to its parent. If you want to center the elements set the parent div's (`.center_grid`) position to relative and use `margin: auto`, it will have the same effect.

Also set your fixed menu's position to center by using `transform:translateX(-50)` and set width to 56%.

```css
.center_grid {
  max-width: 56%;
  flex-basis: 56%;
  width: 56%;
  /*position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;*/
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu_card_warapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  display: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px black solid;
  width: 56%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Stack overflow answer reference: ['transform3d' not working with position: fixed children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children/15256339#15256339)

Your updated [codesandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-jpia35?file=styles%2FHome.module.css) and live preview [link](https://nextjs-tdbx6i--3000.local.webcontainer.io/)

Comment: This solution is okay. But I nee transform for parent element because when screen size change transform is easy to handle the position. I there any other way to fixed child element as position: fixed