# Chrome - Fixed bar moving in certain pages

Tags: html, css

I am getting this strange behavior in chrome.....Fixed bar (top bar) is moving with scroll.

It works fine in FF but moves up in Chrome. I can not figure out why.

Base on a comment in post [Fixed element disappears in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258877/fixed-element-disappears-in-chrome)

I added overflow:auto to HTML, BODY, then it works in Chrome.

I dont understand why it did not work and then why it works with overflow:auto.

Anybody experienced the same problem?

I was not sure if its OK to post link to websites but I am doing it with no hidden agenda. I need to fix this issue. Please help!

http://www.itraintowin.com/vItem/Basketball

The same page works fine in Firefox

Comment: You should move the fixed element to the end of the document ... seems like an issue with z-index ...

Comment: remove the `position: absolute` from the elements inside the fixed header, and you really should move it to the bottom and remove the z-index too ... all you need is to clean up your css files. No js at all.