# position: fixed element disappearing on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a sidebar (which is position:fixed) and there's a "tab" thing.

[image: Tab]

[image: Open sidebar]

First picture shows closed sidebar (tab only), and second one is active sidebar. The problem ONLY occurs when I change route using `HashLocation` in **react-router**. When I go straight into proper URL it's all fine.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258877/fixed-element-disappears-in-chrome), but the problem is I'm already using `transform: translate` to open and hide sidebar.

If I apply this fix, It shows but element on sidebar are disappearing.

Rule for the sidebar looks like this:

```
.landscape-sidebar {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX($landscape-sidebar-width);
  transition: $landscape-sidebar-transition-time transform $landscape-sidebar-transition-type;
  width: $landscape-sidebar-width;
  z-index: $level-4;

  &.show {
    transform: translateX(0);

    .content:hover:before {
      background-color: $landscape-sidebar-background-color;
    }
  }
}
```

Related `render()` method from react component ([full component here](https://gist.github.com/kasperekt/6ea7f4778d41d571de45)):

```
render() {
    const sidebarClass = classNames({
      'landscape-sidebar': true,
      'show': this.state.isOpen,
    });

    return (
      <div className={ sidebarClass }>
        <div
          className="content"
          ref="sidebarContent"
          onWheel={ this.handleScroll }
        >
          <span
            ref="tab"
            onClick={ this.toggleSidebar }
            className="tab"
          />
          { this.props.children }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Is there any other fix for that problem?

*I can't be using `position:absolute` because it's causing Firefox to display scrollbars due to `transform:translate`*

Comment: *"The problem ONLY occurs when I change route using HashLocation in react-router."* Perhaps providing related code would be useful

Comment: It's basic `<Link>` element from **react-router**, that's the way of transitioning between routes. I don't know what code could I give you

Comment: @TomaszKasperek The relevant HTML and JavaScript would be a good start.