# Chrome mobile position fixed bug on scroll

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile

In my site I have a problem with footer during scrolling

http://m.calciomercato.com/

With google chrome the banner is "detached" from the lower side during scrolling.

I tried to update jquery and jquery mobile but without results.

Thanks.

Comment: Working fine for me on Lollipop 5.1, Chrome 47.0.2526.83.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots or something of what you're seeing? What version of mobile chrome are you using?

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: You probably shouldn't include a footer on pages that scroll infinitely. Unless the footer is position: fixed like the header, it will always be appearing and disappearing again.

Comment: is it "detached" by 1px by any chance? that's the only thing i noticed.

Answer (score 8):

While scrolling the page on a mobile phone, the recalculation of the footer-position is not triggered all the time whill 'dragging' the page. The solution is:

a) avoid fixed positions on mobile website (on such a small screen, why are you annoying visitors with an ad that's always there?)

b) Try the `webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` fix as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764086/4832878).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a CSS or jquery issue.
your banner images are too small ( Size : 300 * 203 ) that's why it's detached with fullwidth.

You need to just upload fullwidth images ( Size : 1200 * 500).