# fixed rotated elements disappears on scroll in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, polymer, web-component

I'm having some problems finding the cause where rotated elements and their content disappears when scrolling down in my polymer app with chrome.

The problem happens when a rotated element that is fixed is placed within  a `app-header-layout` element and there is a  `paper-input` element present.

The problem still persists in shadow DOM rendering.

This is the smallest reproducible snippet that I've managed to produce.
https://jsbin.com/celarureyo/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">

  <script>
    window.Polymer = {
      dom: 'shady'
    };
  </script>

  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      font-family: Noto, Roboto;
      color: white;
      background-color: #eee;
    }

    paper-input {
      padding: 24px;
    }

    #content {
      height: 200vh;
    }

    #rotated-fixed-box {
      position: fixed;
      background-color: tomato;
      width: 64px;
      height: 64px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      bottom: 32px;
      left: 32px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    #regular-fixed-box {
      position: fixed;
      background-color: #0097B2;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 64px;
      height: 64px;
      bottom: 32px;
      left: 128px;
    }

    #rotated-inner-box {
      background-color: tomato;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
  </style>

  <body>

    <app-header-layout id="header-layout" has-scrolling-region>

      <div id="content">
        <paper-input label="This is weird"></paper-input>

        <div id="rotated-fixed-box">text</div>

        <div id="regular-fixed-box">
          <div id="rotated-inner-box">text</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </app-header-layout>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should open an issue on Polymer's site since it's bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adding `translateZ(0)` to the rotated elements forces the browser to use hardware acceleration to access the device’s graphical processing unit (GPU) to make pixels fly and keeps them painted on scroll down.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25922011/6017784)

I have created a issue on the chromium tracker regarding this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=700333